# Почему падает скорость кадров, при включении функции обработки изображения в ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c, изображения, камера

Код ниже содержит:

1. Камеру (`SetupCaptureSession`).
2. Функцию обработки изображений, которая выводит картинку в виде шума на экран. (`-(void)setPicture`)
3. Счетчик кадров в виде строки.

   При отключении функции обработки изображений(`-(void)setPicture`) , средняя скорость снятая со счетчика кадров = 25 кадров в секунду. При включении функции обработки изображений, средняя скорость (по счётчику) падает до 15-17 кадров в секунду.

**ViewController.m**

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>

@implementation ViewController

@synthesize myImage;   //UIImage
@synthesize imageView; //ImageView
    
@synthesize rect;      //CGRect
@synthesize session;   //AvCaptureSession

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
   [self setupCaptureSession]; //создание сессии
   
}

//метод создающий сессию съемки
- (void)setupCaptureSession
{
    
    NSError *error = nil;
    session = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];
    
    session.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetMedium;
    
    AVCaptureDevice *device = [AVCaptureDevice
                               defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
   
    AVCaptureDeviceInput *input = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:device error:&error];
    
    if (!input) {
    }
    
    [session addInput:input];
    
    AVCaptureVideoDataOutput *output = [[AVCaptureVideoDataOutput alloc] init];
    
    dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_queue_create("myQueue", NULL);
    [output setSampleBufferDelegate:self queue:queue];// create Sample buffer
    [session addOutput:output];
    [session startRunning];
    
}

//функция вызывается при приходе нового кадра в камеру
 
- (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput

didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer

       fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection

{
    
    NSString *text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"N = %d", N]; //создается строка в глобальной переменной "N"
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        // Update UI
        self.Label.text = text; //перезапись строки (подсчёт кадров) 
        [self setPicture]; //привязка отрисовки картинки к камере
       
    });
    
    NSLog(text); //print same string in console

    N++; //здесь реализован счетчик кадров, которые пришли с начала сессии 

}

//метод отвечающий за отрисовку шума и вывод его на экран.
-(void)setPicture {
    NSLog(@"SetPicture was calling");
    if(imageView!=NULL)
    {//Дополнительное гашение imageView
        [imageView removeFromSuperview];
        imageView = NULL; //Убрать"!
     
    }
    int width = 352; //размеры
    int height = 288;
    
    size_t bufferLength = width * height * 4; //
    uint8_t* pixels = (uint8_t*)malloc(bufferLength); //unsigned char
    for (int i = 0; i < bufferLength/2; i++) {
        pixels[i] = rand() % 255;
    }
    
    CGColorSpaceRef space = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    
    CGContextRef ctx = CGBitmapContextCreate(pixels, width, height, 8, width * 4, space, kCGBitmapByteOrderDefault | kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast); // указатель void * __nullable data
    
    CGImageRef toCGImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(ctx);
    UIImage * uiimage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:toCGImage];
    
    CGImageRelease(toCGImage);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(space);
    CGContextRelease(ctx);
    free(pixels);
    
    myImage = uiimage;
    //
    
    rect = self.view.bounds; //Вынесли в член класса
    
    if(imageView == NULL)
    {
        imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:rect];
        imageView.image = myImage;
    [self.view addSubview:imageView];
      NSLog(@"NULL");
    } else
    {
        [imageView setNeedsDisplay];
        NSLog(@"Dewnull");
    }
    
}

 @end
```

**ViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreMedia/CoreMedia.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>


int N = 0; //глобальная переменная для подсчета кадров. 

@interface ViewController : UIViewController

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *Label; //строка для
@property AVCaptureSession *session;
@property UIImage* myImage;
@property  UIImageView *imageView; 
@property  CGRect rect; //прямоугольное графическое пространство

- (void)setupCaptureSession;


- (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput
didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer
       fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection;
      
-(void)setPicture; //Функция отрисовки шума


 
@end
```

Мне трудно понять с чем связано падение скорости кадров. Толи аппарат слабенький (512 мб оперативы). То ли `ImageView` отрисовка->гашение пожирает память. То ли многопоточность страдает.

**Вопрос:**

Что нужно изменить в коде, чтобы при вызове функции `setPicture` скорость кадров не падала?

Comment: а что это за картинка, что на ней и зачем она нужна?

Comment: сделайте заранее 5 картинок и меняйте  когда надо

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko не то.

Answer (score 0):

ваша функция очень сильно нагружает то ли cpu, то ли gpu. не важно. оптимизировать ее вряд ли получится. Вам надо искать альтернативный подход к задаче. как я уже писал в комментарии - заранее создать 5 картинок и их использовать. или что-то подобное

Comment: Спасибо, ищем (продолжаем). OpenGL пробуем.